# Remain at the same vertical coordinate when loading more data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I have a load more button which loads more data to a component. However, after pressing the load button the user is scrolled at the bottom of screen since the load more button is also located at the bottom of the screen.

The user has to scroll up to see the loaded content. Is there any way to make the user to remain at the same vertical coordinate when pressing the button?

Comment: so the loaded content is at the top of the page? if so, why not put the loaded content at the bottom of the page? and could you post out the codes you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

One solution if you like to scroll to original position where the `Load More` button locates:

1. uses `ref` to mark the related VNodes (scrolling Container `ref=container` and the anchor `ref=test`)
2. when `Load Button` is pressed, get current button position
3. After new content is loaded, call `scrollTo` method to scroll to the position it got in Step 2 inside `nextTick` callback

```js
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
    return {
      rows: Array.from({length: 100}).map((_, index) => index),
      current: 5,
      currentCoords: {top: 0, left: 0}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedRows: function () {
      return this.rows.slice(0, this.current)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore: function () {
      this.currentCoords.top = this.$refs.test.offsetTop
      this.currentCoords.left = this.$refs.test.offsetLeft
      this.current += 15
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.container.scrollTo(this.currentCoords.left, this.currentCoords.top - 10)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div ref="container" style="max-height: 200px;overflow:auto">
            <p v-for="(row, index) in computedRows" :key="index">{{row}}</p>
            <button ref="test" @click="loadMore()">Load More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit to make it work for my scenario. However, thank you for making me aware of $nextTick function. That was the key to make it work. I did not put any refs. I just stored the x and y position in the load more method ( var xLastPosition = window.pageXOffset). Then inside the nextTick method I used the         window.scroll(xLastPosition, yLastPosition);